# column not appearing in shipment page admin

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.9

I have created a custom module and below is the installer code.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$shipmentTable = $installer->getTable('sales/shipment');
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($shipmentTable, 'appointment_date', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, array(
        ), 'Appointment Date');


$installer->endSetup();
```

when i check core_resources table i found the setup entry and also i found entry in eav_attribute with entity id 8.

but when i open shipment page from admin i saw no column there . i have reindexed data and my cache is disabled please suggest the solution